# XPath variable for searching attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am writing a c# code which requires me to parse an xml file. The statement that i need is

```
  XmlDocument xmlt = new XmlDocument();
  xmlt.Load(XMLFile1.xml");
  XmlNode node = xmlt.SelectSingleNode("//abc/data[@name='xyz']/value");
```

where abc is the root node.
I am searching the data attribute @name to match with xyz, what should i do if instead of hard coding xyz i need a variable, say name_var. I basically need a code which performs the function so that i cn put @name=name_var instead of xyz.

name_var is varied in the c# code

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` methods do not provide an overload to provide some variable resolution so all you can do is construct a string e.g.

```
string name = "xyx";
XmlNode node = xmlt.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("abc/data[@name = '{0}']/value", name));
```

Of course that approach breaks as soon as the `name` value contains a single quote `'` character. If you need variable resolution in XPath then look into XPathNavigator, it allows that with some effort: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd567715%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.