# Using a variable in selectsinglenodes ..... 'string construct' workaround (using VBA?)

Tags: xml, vba, nodes, domdocument, selectnodes

So I'm trying to do something this

```
dim myOrderID As Integer
myOrderID = 1
Set Ordercount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//order[orderid=myOrderID]")
```

....in other words, embed a variable in the selection criteria for selectNodes . From the googling I've done, apparently I can't (ref: [XPath variable for searching attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118351/xpath-variable-for-searching-attribute) ), but I can perhaps use something called a string construct...I have no idea what that means ...or more to the point how I'd do it in VBA?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Set Ordercount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//order[orderid=" & myOrderID & "]")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work - see the resulting error in my screenscrape.... https://s10.postimg.org/tvoy98vop/err.jpg

Comment: That's not what I posted

Comment: Tim, you are quite right ...it's not what you suggested (in my defence it's late & I'm keyboard/screen weary!). Your proposed solution worked a charm & you've saved me a lot of grief having to go another way for not being able to do this - Many thanks!

Comment: @peskywinnets You should *accept* this answer since it solved the problem in question. More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Now done...the protocol is all new to me so thanks for the heads up.